# How to trim an Image in Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, html5-canvas, trim

I've an image and I want to remove blank borders at the corner from it.
How can I trim an Image in Javascript? Will be better whitout huge libraries.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of an "CanvasRenderingContext2D" object (canvas element), you can do what ever you want with your image. Just resize the canvas and use the drawImage() method:

```
function trimImage(img, posX, posY, recWidth, recHeight)
{
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = recWidth;
    canvas.height = recHeight;
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.drawImage(img, -posX, -posY);
    img.parentNode.replaceChild(canvas, img);
}
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function()
{
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = "image.png";
    document.body.appendChild(img);
    img.onload = function() { trimImage(img, 10, 5, img.width - 40, img.height - 80); }
});
```

The canvas element *is an* image. If you need a image tag, you can switch it back by using toDataURL() to get an src attribute.

replace

```
img.parentNode.replaceChild(canvas, img);
```

with

```
var newImg = document.createElement('img');
newImg.src = canvas.toDataURL();
img.parentNode.replaceChild(newImg, img);
```

I think a new image is necessary, to refire an onload event.