# Setting png image as a div background

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have a png image which has transparent space around the actual image.

like this

[image: png image]

I want to place this image as a background for a div. But the div should only display the image without the transparent area around it.

This is what I have now. https://jsfiddle.net/qhoty913/8/

How can I make sure that the inner div image starts from the actual image and it wont have the blank spaces around it. Is it possible without modifying the actual png image file?

```css
.imgBck {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png');
  background-size: cover;
  border-style: dotted;
}

.borderDiv {
  border-style: solid
}
```

```html
<div class="borderDiv">
  <div class="imgBck">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How should HTML and CSS know what parts of the image are not part of the image itself? You need to edit it manually by only showing an partial image or better yet crop the image yourself to contain only the parts you need.

Comment: Perhaps [this canvas trim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38814646/how-to-trim-an-image-in-javascript) plus [this transparency detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23255825/how-to-detect-shape-on-a-transparent-canvas)

Comment: @httpanand No it does not. They want the transparent part to not be part of the background but be removed or outside the borders

Comment: @mplungjan yes. looking for something like that transparency detection. I thought there might be some magic css properties to do so. Looks like there isn't

Answer (score 1):

In order to remove the blank spaces around it, you should remove the margin you have added. In addition to that, I am not sure what you mean with your question, but you can try playing around with the `background-size` and `background-position` properties to make the image look the way you like. I played around with the code a bit, and came up with this simple fix, yet I am not completely sure if this is what you are looking for. By making the divs more fluid, you can get rid of the transparent spaces you are mentioning:

```css
.imgBck {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png');
  background-position: 10px;
  background-size: cover;
}

.borderDiv {
  border-style: solid
}
```

```html
<div class="borderDiv">
  <div class="imgBck">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can copy OP's snippet into your answer, change and save it. Like I just did for you

Comment: This solution could work for one example, but it would be a real big job to do this if you have +100 photos :)

Answer (score 0):

The aspect ratio of the containing `div` is equal to the aspect ratio of the image => 300x200 (fixed 'px' units) and 800x600 (image physical size) => aspect ratio: `3:2`. Therefore, you cannot resize the background to 'lose' the excess space without cutting parts of the cubes or get some unwanted width vs. height stretching.

This is due to the fact that to lose excess space, the actual aspect ratio of the containing `div` has to be `1.125:1`, or `width: 225px; height: 200px`.
Once this has been established, you can use `background-position` and `background-size` to resize the `background-image` and lose the excess space.

Please be aware that this method is very image specific and proper cropping of a single background image is likely the preferred method.

**snippet**

```css
.imgBck {
  margin:  10px;
  width : 225px; /* from 300px */
  height: 200px;

  background-image   : url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png');
  background-position: 47% 20%; /* ADDED */
  background-size    : 140%;    /* from 'cover' */
  background-repeat  : no-repeat;

  border-style: dotted;
}
.borderDiv {
  border-style: solid
}
```

```html
<div class="borderDiv">
  <div class="imgBck">
  </div>
</div>
```